# How to use postfix header_checks with zarafa outgoing mail

Tags: postfix, cleanup

I'm using zarafa with postfix. For privacy reasons I want to filter client internal IP-addresses and stuff like this. To do so I've added the following to `master.cf`:

`submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd [...] -o cleanup_service_name=subcleanup [...]`

and further down the file:

`subcleanup unix n       -       -       -       0       cleanup -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks`

which works perfectly for clients delivering their mail through the submission port. But my zarafa is of course not using the submission port to send mail, hence it doesn't hit the subcleanup routine and outgoing mails contain a very nice X-Mailer: Zarafa-exact_version header which is rather unsatisfying. Is there any way to make zarafa use the subcleanup routine?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try configuring Zarafa Spooler (`spooler.cfg`) to use the SMTP port you're running the 'submission' on.

Alternatively, configure your standard smtpd line in the `master.cf` to also hit the `subcleanup` routine like you've set up for 'submission' now. Then it will affect *all* mail passing the Postfix MTA on the standard port.

Comment: You sire, are a genius. Sometimes it's just too simple ;-)